# Error while importing NSWorkspace from AppKit in python

Tags: python, macos, appkit

Even after installing AppKit, I am not able to import NSWorkspace from it.

This is the error I am receiving:
ImportError: cannot import name 'NSWorkspace' from 'AppKit'

I have tried installing pyobjc, but still it's not solving the problem

Comment: Same problem here, did you solve it?